# how to check if MS deploy worked properly

Tags: powershell, webdeploy

I am deploying a web site using power script, server is running on windows 7 with IIS 7.5
I am using following code to deploy the application 
         `$arguments = [string[]]@(
            "-verb:sync",
            "-source:package='$PackagePath'",
            "-dest:auto,computerName='$PublishUrl',AuthType='NTLM'",
             "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='$($WebApp)'",
            "-allowUntrusted")

    Start-Process $msdeploy -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait`

above script is working fine.

I want to catch the negative case.When I disable the web deploy agent service on the machine,it throws a message (Power shell is not treating this as error or exception)

> Error Code: ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
>   More Information: Could not connect to the remote computer ("localhost") using the specified process ("Web Deployment
>   Agent Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is start
>   ed on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMO
>   TESVC.
>   Error: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
>   Error count: 1.

How can I catch this in powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with the following command:

```
$arguments = [string[]]@(
        "-verb:sync",
        "-source:package='$PackagePath'",
        "-dest:auto,computerName='$PublishUrl',AuthType='NTLM'",
         "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='$($WebApp)'",
        "-allowUntrusted")

    #Restore IIS
    $proc = Start-Process $msdeploy -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
    $handle = $proc.Handle
    $proc.WaitForExit();

    if ($proc.ExitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Warning "$_ exited with status code $($proc.ExitCode)"
    }
```

The secret here is the "-PassThru". Check out [microsoft documentation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/18/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects/).

Comment: Thank you @Jorge - this problem has been dogging me for a couple of days and your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this at the end of your script:

```
if ($Error.Count -gt 0)
{
    $Error | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red }
    exit -1;
}
```